# How to adjust intellij inspections for angularjs / html

Tags: html, angularjs, intellij-idea, inspections

I'm writing angularjs app in intellij. In html templates I get a lot of inspection errors/warnings for the correct code):

1. translate="xx.yy.zz.oo" - Wrong attribute value
2. class="row tile-element" - "Expecting new line or a semicolon" (between two classes)
3. name="{{'xxx'+$index}}" - identifier or string literal or numeric literal expected

Is there a simple way to make the inspections reasonable ?

Comment: switch to VSCODE :p

Comment: Have you tried Webstorm it is intellj for webdevelopment ?
You have maybe to add some plugins in the original intellj to make it suitable for webdev

Comment: Actually I'm doing full-stack development - I need the whole IntelliJ. I have heard that both tools work the same. In most cases IntelliJ is really good and intuitive - there must be a way to easily fix this issue.